# Would like to know how to add some code to make my program be able to deal with letters being inputted

Tags: python, math

My program is a simple arithmetic quiz however i want to know how to make it so that it doesn't just stop when i don't enter in an integer.

```
questionNo=0
score=0

name=input("What is your name?")
print("Welcome ",name," to your arithmetic quiz!")

time.sleep(1)

while questionNo<10:
    function=random.randint(1,3)
    if function==1:
        rNumber1=random.randint(1,100)
        rNumber2=random.randint(1,100)
        print("Question is : ", rNumber1," + ",rNumber2)
        guess=int(input("What is the answer?"))
        ans=rNumber1+rNumber2
        if ans==guess:
            print("Correct!")
            score+=1
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("Wrong")
            time.sleep(1)

    elif function==2:
        rNumber1=random.randint(1,10)
        rNumber2=random.randint(1,10)
        print("Question is : ", rNumber1," X ",rNumber2)
        guess=int(input("What is the answer?"))
        ans=rNumber1*rNumber2
        if ans==guess:
            print("Correct!")
            score+=1
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("Wrong")
            time.sleep(1)

    else:
        rNumber1=random.randint(1,100)
        rNumber2=random.randint(1,100)
        print("Question is : ", rNumber1," - ",rNumber2)
        guess=int(input("What is the answer?"))
        ans=rNumber1-rNumber2
        if ans==guess:
            print("Correct!")
            score+=1
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("Wrong")
            time.sleep(1)
    questionNo+=1

print("Well done ",name,"! You got ",score,"/10")
```

Comment: Add you code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com after making required changes to discuss how to make it readable not just working.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your call to `int(input())` in a `try-except` clause.
Trying to convert a value of type `str` to `int` will always raise a `ValueError` **[exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)**.

So, wherever you want to catch this *illegal* conversion, meaning, whenever `int(input())` is called, wrap it in the try-except in order to **[handle](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)** it:

```
try:
    guess = int(input("What is the answer?"))
except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a number as the answer!")
    continue
```

And don't increment the `questionNo` counter in the `except` clause in order to keep the same number of questions in total.

Comment: This code as it stands, while trigger a new question each time  the exception triggers. I.e. if you want to avoid a question, you could just type in some characters...

Comment: Well, sure. If you want to 'avoid' a question, just increment `questionNo`, if not, don't.

Comment: Your exception handling will always end the loop prematurely, and thusly create a new question. I'd consider that a bug, but your mileage may vary.